# Ruby on rails - Change date format when importing csv to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a csv file to import to sqlite3 in ruby on rails. The csv file has a date column which is formatted as MM/DD/YYYY. The date in sqlite3 is formatted as DD/MM/YYYY. How can I convert to the same format without changing the csv file?

Comment: In your sqlite database, date is stored in an actual date column, I hope?

Comment: Yes, it is stored in a column

Comment: Obviously, it's a column, but what is the type of that column?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev SQLite doesn't actually support `date` column types, you're supposed to use `text` and store dates as ISO-8601 strings.

Comment: @muistooshort: insane!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev SQLite's type system is, um, *interesting*. It is reasonable for embedded use but strange for "real" database work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're storing your dates in SQLite in the wrong format. From the fine [SQLite manual](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype):

> **2.2. Date and Time Datatype**
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as `TEXT`, `REAL`, or `INTEGER` values:
>
> - `TEXT` as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - [...]

The recommended way of storing a date in SQLite would be in a `text` column using the ISO-8601 format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) so that you can use SQLite's functions for working with them and they'll compare/sort correctly.

The sensible thing to do is to parse the incoming dates use [`Date.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) from the Ruby standard library:

```
date = Date.strptime(date_string_from_csv, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

and then convert that to an ISO-8601 date string using the [`Date#iso8601`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-iso8601) method:

```
date_for_sqlite = date.iso8601
```

and then send `date_for_sqlite` into the database. As a bonus, any sane database will understand ISO-8601 formatted dates unambiguously so you shouldn't have to worry about this issue if you switch databases.

If you must use your non-standard `DD/MM/YYYY` format then use [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime):

```
date_for_sqlite = date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Thank you. My csv file has multiple rows and I use `namespace :db do
  task :import_csv => :environment do
    CSV.foreach("sample_landslides.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
      Landslide.create!(row.to_hash)` the whole file to rails. Im thinking of delete the current date column and import a converted date column date column into it. How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you drop the table and then re-import it with the proper date format? Is there new data in there that you need to preserve?